# text-wrap is not working

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I am new to AngularJS and Web Development.

I have a following code:

```css
.jdContext {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #428bca;
  font-weight: bold
}

.jdContextInManageResume {
  display: block;
  width: 539px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <span ng-if="jdSelected" class="jdContext jdContextInManageResume" ng-show="isjdDeleted">
    <span>Company   :  {{companyName}}</span>
    <br>
    <span>JobDescription : abcd abcd abcd abdc adcdjcd cjdndjcdc cdncdcndjcdc </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
</div>
```

I tried using the `wrap` but its not getting wrapped.

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Nothing is wrapping because your container is wide enough to fit the entire line.

Comment: I have some burrons which are in the same row.

Comment: So, because of that this text goes under the button

Comment: Actually, word wrap is also happening. But this text is going under the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width` from `jdContextInManageResume` .
Check the below css it will work

```
.jdContext {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #428bca;
  font-weight: bold
}

.jdContextInManageResume {
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if its helpfull,and textwrap works when your content dont gets enough space .

```
    .textwrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
}
```